# Cookie add on button hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, onclick, jquery-events

I have a problem with adding a cookie. Read a couple of answers, but it's hard to understand if you never worked with them before.

What I basically want is to add a cookie if someone click on the specified button. So for example, if person clicked on the "like button", hidden content will be revealed no matter if he go forward/back or refresh page and cookie shall be removed after a couple of days.

What I used to hide the content is following:

***HTML:***

```
<div id="fd">
    <p>Button from below will become active once you hit like button!</p>
    <div id="get-it">
        <a class="button"><img src="img/get-button.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='feedback' style='display:none'></div>
```

***javascript:***

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
    $('#feedback').fadeIn().html('<p>Thank you. You may proceed now!</p><br/><div id="get-it"><a class="button2" href="pick.html"><img src="img/get-button.png"></a></div>');
    $('#fd').fadeOut();
});
```

However if I hit refresh or go back/forward on the content page, it will be hidden again. This is reason why I want to add a cookie on button hit. Anyone who can give me some explanations or example code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suggest using the [jQuery-cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Here's a few examples of usage:

```
// Create a cookie
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');

// Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });

// Read a cookie
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => 'the_value'
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => null

// EDIT
// Attaching to a button click (jQuery 1.7+) and set cookie
$("#idOfYourButton").on("click", function () {
    $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
});

// Attaching to a button click (jQuery < 1.7) and set cookie
$("#idOfYourButton").click(function () {
    $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
});
```

You will also need to add a check that the cookie exists (for when the browser is reloaded:

```
if ($.cookie('the_cookie')) {
    // Apply rule you want to apply
    $('.ClassToSelect').css("display", "none");
}
```

Comment: Yep, I saw this in one of the questions here as answer. What I don't understand as mentioned, is how to integrate it on button hit. I am struggling really hard.

Comment: @NenadNovakovic, See last example marked `EDIT`. To be honest, if you're struggling with attaching to event handlers, you need to go through some JS tutorials.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for that. A couple of minutes, to try. I bet it is problem solved. Will mark it up if it is!

Comment: @NenadNovakovic, mark up for my effort, mark as answer if it works ;-)

Comment: @NenadNovakovic, Respectfully, SO is not a place where people write all your code for you. The example I've given shows you how to set a cookie AND retrieve the value of the cookie that was set. I've given you everything you need to make this work. I will tell you that your selector is incorrect on your form. `.button2` currently selects nothing.

Comment: Okay just don't get mad ;) 
I will keep struggling if you say that it is everything I required. Cheers!

Comment: @NenadNovakovic, I'm not mad at all - just wanted to let you know what's up :)

Comment: Still nothing man. Either I am totally dumb or this is just too hard :) ! Was reading some more answers and saw that ID should be added on button href actually... Still no idea if cookie is being added and i am sure that there is something missing. If cookie is added, another script cannot know should it show content for the cookie. I need more help :(

Answer (score 2):

Instead of cookies, I recommend you use [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: What about browsers that don't support `localStorage`?

Comment: That's a valid question; localStorage is widely supported and better than cookies, but if you're targeting an even wider set of browser versions, then jQuery-cookie is even widelyer.

Comment: I see for localstorage is also sayin' it can be for session (one time) or local (forever)... I need something that will be for lets say 5 days , such as cookies...

Comment: Then cookies will more convenient from a development standpoint, although in theory you [can do expiration with localStorage](http://blog.anhangzhu.com/2011/07/20/html-5-local-storage-with-expiration/).